# Unable to store unicode sting in MySQL

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I need to store this unicode string in MySQL

```
Příliš žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy.On sangen hauskaa, että polkupyörä on maanteiden jokapäiväinen ilmiö.
```

but whenever I store this string and execute the query from phpMyAdmin the string is stored as

```
P?íliš žlu?ou?ký k?? úp?l ?ábelské ódy.On sangen hauskaa, että polkupyörä on maanteiden jokapäiväinen ilmiö.
```

Can any one tell me why this is happening? I am using MySQL 5.5.20 and character set of both table and database is utf8 -- UTF-8 Unicode and collation is utf_unicode_ci

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the character set your phpmyadmin install is using.

Comment: how to check that ? by the way i am using navicat